# forward voice call *and* invoke webhook

Tags: twilio, webhooks, twilio-twiml

Before asking this question I searched "forward voice call and invoke webhook" but did not find what I'm looking for.

I have successfully configured a Twilio phone number such that if an incoming call is SMS it goes to my webhook, but if it's voice it forwards to my mobile phone.

Now I'd like those voice calls to also call a webhook (different than the webhook above)  *in addition to* forwarding the call to my mobile phone.  I want this so I can capture the caller's number, and the called number, (To/From) and store those in my database.

Can anyone point me to an article on this?

Comment: How have you configured it to forward the call. Is that via Twimlbins instead of using a webhook?

Comment: Thank, philnash.   Yes, I created TwiMLBin;  ...<Dial>#######</Dial>, and configured VOICE to point to that.  Now Voice calls are forwarded, and SMS calls are sent to my webhook.  This is the desired behavior.  But now I want to add functionality such that voice calls, in addition to being forwarding, have their the To/From information sent to a web API method.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Can you set up to use a webhook instead of TwimlBins, like with your SMS config, but return the TwiML from your webhook?

Comment: Sorry, I should have replied to this back when.   I have taken your advice and configured the number to use webhook.  There I capture the phone information (from/to numbers) to my database and then use TwiML to forward the call to another number.  Does the job perfectly.  Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Glad this has helped! Could you mark the answer as correct so that others can see that if they reach this question too. Thanks!

Comment: When I click to up-vote I'm told that I need "15 reputation" for that to register.  :-/

Comment: There should be a tick next to the answer that you can check which accepts the answer. I don't think you need reputation for that.

Comment: Ah, got it.  And thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to receive the webhook too, then I recommend you don't use TwiMLBins at all. Just set up your URL that you want the webhook to send the data to to respond with the TwiML to forward the call too.

Comment: Great, thanks.  But how can I tell when the call is voice and when it's SMS?  I would only want Voice calls to be call-forwarded on.

Comment: You can use a different path for each webhook, say www.example.com/messages for SMS and www.example.com/calls for phone calls.

Comment: Of course.  How silly of me.  I've implemented per your advice.  Works perfectly.   Greatly appreciated, Sir.